# Reading of 味 as a suffix in "X-flavour" /　as a counter in "X flavours"

Tags: readings

This question brought to you by [the existence of カレー味のラムネ](http://www.yomiuri.co.jp/gourmet/news/business/20130606-OYT8T00390.htm)

In my head, the reading here is あじ。 But I know 七味唐辛子{しちみとうがらし}, so it seems like as a counter it's み。

I'm almost 100% sure that カレーの味 would be "あじ", but what about カレー味?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

七味{しちみ} itself is a morpheme with a Chinese original, thus the `音読み{おんよみ}` 七味{しちみ}. The pronunciation rooted from ancient Chinese. 酸味{さんみ} is a similar example.

In the contrary, カレーの味 and カレー味 are lexical items clearly not rooted from Chinese words. `カレー味` contains 2 **free morphemes** `カレー` and `味{あじ}`. So, a `訓読み{くんよみ}`, 味{あじ}, would be appropriate in this case.

There are many examples provided by this snack:
[うまい棒](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%86%E3%81%BE%E3%81%84%E6%A3%92)

You can see they have listed a lot of flavors there. Most of them are combinations of a `Western origin word` + `味{あじ}`

**Edited**:

For 塩味{しおあじ}, a thing 塩{しお} that actually exists make it quite detachable , resulting free morphemes `しお` + `あじ`. It is very like the `カレー`+`あじ` in the original question. However, like `辛味` it is heavily linked together. One thing you could check is, try adding a の between to see if it makes sense. Like 塩の味{しおのあじ} makes sense, but things like 辛の味{からのあじ} doesn't make sense.

Also, you can see 辛味{からみ} 甘味{あまみ} 苦味{にがみ} are basic tastes the one could sense. The pure sensory counterpart for salty is 鹹味{かんみ}

Comment: What about cases like 紅茶味? Still あじ？

Comment: Yes we have [紅茶味]{こうちゃあじ} [抹茶味]{まっちゃあじ} [塩味]{しおあじ} [醤油味]{しょうゆあじ} グリーンアップル[味]{あじ} etc. and [辛味]{からみ} [甘味]{あまみ} [苦味]{にがみ} [風味]{ふうみ} うま[味]{み}... and 「プリッツ[七味味]{しちみあじ}」 :D

Comment: `紅茶` + `味` Yes, it is still あじ

Comment: Okay, so ~あじ for specific flavours and ~み for more generic tastes like sweet, sour... but it's not 塩味{えんみ}?  Or is it like the difference between "salty" and "salted"?

Comment: @nkjt We also have [塩味]{しおみ} and [塩気]{しおけ} for "saltiness" but 塩味 is normally read しおあじ. Casually we say しょっぱい, [塩味]{しおあじ}が強い/きつい, [塩]{しお}が多い/きつい for "(too) salty". I also say [辛]{から}い (but maybe it's only in Kansai.)